# What is the difference between Session.getAllTrackables and Frame.getUpdatedTrackables?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

Do both return all trackables known for now?

Why do we need both?

When should call which one?

Same question is for `Session.getAllAnchors` and `Frame.getUpdatedAnchors`.

Answer (score 3):

Global **`Session.getAllTrackables`** returns the list of **all known trackables**. If plane detection is enabled this list includes `Planes`, as well as `Points` created as a side-effect of calls to `hitTest(float, float)` or `createAnchor(Pose)`.

Example:

```
planeRenderer.drawPlanes(session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class),
                         camera.getDisplayOrientedPose(), 
                         projmtx);
```

As you can see here `planeRenderer` class is for drawing planes. It uses a `.drawPlanes()` method to render any of the identified planes the ARCore session has identified using the view and projection matrices. It passes all the planes in thru a call to `getAllTrackables(Plane.class)`.

But local **`Frame.getUpdatedTrackables`** returns the **trackables of a particular type** that were changed by the `update()` that returned this `Frame`. To retrieve all changed trackables a ***filterType*** may be `Trackable.class` or `Point.class` or `Plane.class`. This method gets fired whenever screen frame is updated.

Example:

```
private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) {
    Frame frame = arSceneView.getArFrame();
    Collection updatedAugmentedImages = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
}
```

And a couple of words about `update()`:

```
public Frame update()
```

> Updates the state of the ARCore system. This includes: receiving a new camera frame, updating the location of the device, updating the location of tracking anchors, updating detected planes, etc. This call may cause off-screen OpenGL activity. Because of this, to avoid unnecessary frame buffer flushes and reloads, this call should not be made in the middle of rendering a frame or offscreen buffer. This call may update the pose of all created anchors and detected planes. The set of updated objects is accessible through `getUpdatedTrackables(Class)`.